# Understanding an example of using Bayesian and Frequentist inference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, frequentist

I have problems to understanding the following discussion.

[image]

[image]

The questions are:

1)In "Some computation shows that
this rule had probability 0.083,..." how $0.083$ calculated?(In a different version wrote $.074$)

2)Why "The stopping rule doesn’t affect the posterior distribution"? and i do not understand why it told ? So what?

3)In the discussion, a stopping  rule changed, so likelihood inference changed , but Bayesian not. Is it really a better property? What does that mean? More generally  how can i challenge this discussion? 
Can i find a stopping time rule such  that Frequentist Inference has a good property but bayesian  Inference does not(opposite of the discussion )?  (If it is so finding a rule that bayesian approach has a good property  but  Frequentist Inference does not, means nothing).

For question (1)

$$P_{H_0}(Z_{30}>1.645 \ or \ Z_{20}>1.645)=
P(Z_{30}>1.645)+\mathbb P(Z_{20}>1.645)-P(Z_{30}>1.645 \ and \ Z_{20}>1.645)=
0.1-P(Z_{30}>1.645 \ and \ Z_{20}>1.645)$$
$$P(Z_{30}>1.645 \ and \ Z_{20}>1.645)=P(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{20}X_j +\sum_{j=21}^{30}X_j}{\sqrt{30}}>1.645 \ and \ Z_{20}>1.645)$$

$$=P(\sqrt{20} Z_{20} +\sum_{j=21}^{30}X_j>1.645\sqrt{30} \ and \ Z_{20}>1.645)$$
But I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Source:[casi.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf), 3.3 Flaws in Frequentist Inference (Page 31).

Source: Another version [casi2.pdf](http://www.mediafire.com/file/vcy1lpssa5g52br/Bradley_Efron%252C_Trevor_Hastie_-_Computer_Age_Statistical_Inference__.pdf/file)

Comment: It may not help, but the version I just downloaded states `0.074` where your's says `0.083`. The book title states "Corrected November 10, 2017."

Comment: For me it is 2016(I am not sure!). I see it now for yours.

Comment: The version i use , added at the end of question.

Answer (score 1):

I can only provide a (partial) answer to 1). This is a topic for example addressed by [P. Armitage, C. K. McPherson and B. C. Rowe (1969), Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series A (132), 2, 235-244: "Repeated Significance Tests on Accumulating Data"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2343787?origin=JSTOR-pdf).

They consider simulation, and so I will just follow them:

```
n <- 30

snoop <- function(n){
  x <- rnorm(n)
  t30 <- sum(x)/sqrt(n)
  t20 <- sum(x[1:20])/sqrt(20)

  q <- qnorm(.95)
  return(t20 > q | t30 > q)
}

mean(replicate(1e6, snoop(n)))
```

This returns values around the 0.074 you quote.